# PHP evolt.org login script mysql_close

Tags: php, mysql

I want to try evolt login system.

http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features

I can't find where in this script there is closing connection from mysql. Where in this script mysql_close method is executed? Where mysql_close should be in script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost never necessary to explicitly call `mysql_close` in PHP scripts. The connection is implicitly closed when the script exits.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the connection was opened in persistent mode, the connection is closed when the script exits as part of the normal "cleanup" process.

If it's persistent, then the connection remains open and is returned to the connection pool for re-use by another script.